# pouchdb not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, pouchdb

I have created an application which stores data in a pouch Db (indexed db) .It works fine in Google chrome but fails in Mozilla Firefox. I have attached the error in firebug console : [image]

Answer (score 1):

you likely have a db with the name that already exists, make sure you have an up to date version of pouch and clear the local data for that domain.